# Rails calculate and display average

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, average

I'm trying to average scores within a particularly category. I have a table that contains a list of directors, movies, genres, ratings and scores. When the user clicks on a movie I'd like them to be able to see the average score for all other movies in that genre.

I think that I have to use the average method in conjunction with a condition. That said I haven't been able to find any useful documentation online regarding this specific topic. If someone could point me in the direction of a guide or article that explains how to calculate averages with conditions and display them in a view, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984995/ruby-on-rails-field-average

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Together with other calculations, ActiveRecord provides a method called [average](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average). You can use it by implementing something like this:

```
class Movie
  def self.average_by_genre(genre)
    average(:rating).where(:genre => genre)
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can also implement it as an instance method of the Movie model.

```
class Movie
  def average_rating
    self.class.average(:rating).where(:genre => self.genre)
  end
end
```

This would let you call the method directly from your view.

```
<article>
  <header>
    <h1><%= @movie.title %></h1>
  </header>
  <p>
    <span>Average rating for genre <%= @movie.genre %>:</span> 
    <%= @movie.average_rating  %>
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! How do I go about displaying this average within the view?

Comment: Do you think calculating average should be done in model, view, or decorator?

Answer (score 5):

How about some raw SQL?

```
SELECT AVG(score) FROM movies WHERE category_id = 42
```

Or in rails:

```
Movie.where(category_id: 42).average("score")
```

Read more info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#average

Answer (score 0):

How about you move `SQL` raw query to a `database view`:

```
# movies_view
SELECT m.id, AVG(m.score) avg_score, c.category_id
FROM movies m
JOIN category c
ON m.category_id
```

So you will need to query from the `MovieView`

```
MovieView.find(:movie_id).avg_score
```